# is there a training script running on Intel Iris Xe Graphics intead of Nvidia?

Tags: pytorch, training-data

guys, i'm using a Intel Iris Xe Graphics, i'm looking for a training  script can run on  Intel Iris Xe Graphics. May i use torch==2.0.0+cu118  or torch==1.13.1+cpu? should I remove the arg '--xformers'? how to disable cuda using '--no-cuda', it throws the error when i add this arg.

my training script:

```
...
$lowram = 1
# ============= DO NOT MODIFY CONTENTS BELOW  =====================
# Activate python venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate

$Env:HF_HOME = "huggingface"
$Env:XFORMERS_FORCE_DISABLE_TRITON = "1"
$ext_args = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$launch_args = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

if ($multi_gpu) {
  [void]$launch_args.Add("--multi_gpu")
}

if ($lowram) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--lowram")
}

if ($is_v2_model) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--v2") 
}
else {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--clip_skip=$clip_skip")
}

if ($parameterization) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--v_parameterization")
}

if ($train_unet_only) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--network_train_unet_only")
}

if ($train_text_encoder_only) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--network_train_text_encoder_only")
}

if ($network_weights) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--network_weights=" + $network_weights)
}

if ($reg_data_dir) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--reg_data_dir=" + $reg_data_dir)
}

if ($optimizer_type) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--optimizer_type=" + $optimizer_type)
}

if ($optimizer_type -eq "DAdaptation") {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--optimizer_args")
  [void]$ext_args.Add("decouple=True")
}

if ($network_module -eq "lycoris.kohya") {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--network_args")
  [void]$ext_args.Add("conv_dim=$conv_dim")
  [void]$ext_args.Add("conv_alpha=$conv_alpha")
  [void]$ext_args.Add("algo=$algo")
  [void]$ext_args.Add("dropout=$dropout")
}

if ($noise_offset -ne 0) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--noise_offset=$noise_offset")
}

if ($stop_text_encoder_training -ne 0) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--stop_text_encoder_training=$stop_text_encoder_training")
}

if ($save_state -eq 1) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--save_state")
}

if ($resume) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--resume=" + $resume)
}

if ($min_snr_gamma -ne 0) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--min_snr_gamma=$min_snr_gamma")
} 

if($persistent_data_loader_workers) {
  [void]$ext_args.Add("--persistent_data_loader_workers")
}


# run train
accelerate launch $launch_args --num_cpu_threads_per_process=8 "./sd-scripts/train_network.py" `
  --enable_bucket `
  --pretrained_model_name_or_path=$pretrained_model `
  --train_data_dir=$train_data_dir `
  --output_dir="./output" `
  --logging_dir="./logs" `
  --log_prefix=$output_name `
  --resolution=$resolution `
  --network_module=$network_module `
  --max_train_epochs=$max_train_epoches `
  --learning_rate=$lr `
  --unet_lr=$unet_lr `
  --text_encoder_lr=$text_encoder_lr `
  --lr_scheduler=$lr_scheduler `
  --lr_warmup_steps=$lr_warmup_steps `
  --lr_scheduler_num_cycles=$lr_restart_cycles `
  --network_dim=$network_dim `
  --network_alpha=$network_alpha `
  --output_name=$output_name `
  --train_batch_size=$batch_size `
  --save_every_n_epochs=$save_every_n_epochs `
  --mixed_precision="no" `
  --save_precision="float" `
  --seed="1337" `
  --cache_latents `
  --prior_loss_weight=1 `
  --max_token_length=225 `
  --caption_extension=".txt" `
  --save_model_as=$save_model_as `
  --min_bucket_reso=$min_bucket_reso `
  --max_bucket_reso=$max_bucket_reso `
  --keep_tokens=$keep_tokens `
  --shuffle_caption $ext_args
Write-Output "Train finished"
Read-Host | Out-Null ;
```